# AMD graphics problem - black screen!

Tags: 12.04, ati, graphics, xorg, radeon

I have a laptop HP Pavilion g6-1075er with Ubuntu 12.04 and AMD Radeon HD 6470M on board.
I had default graphics configuration but some problems with xorg occurred.
I had black screen, but I was able to "reset" graphics configuration to some workable state via recovery mode. But this state was slightly different from the default one (Alt+Tab didn't show same 3D selection, Alt+` doesn't work everywhere etc).
So, I decided to revert it to default state. I checked this post http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1517170 and used the following commands:

sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri

sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg

After rebooting I just get a black screen (in normal boot mode I think there is a nonblinking cursor also) and no login window. The same in recovery mode.
So I can't enter any commands.

What can I do?

UPDATE: if I boot to Windows 7, hibernate and then boot to Ubuntu recovery mode, then I get the recovery menu.

By hibernating from Windows 7 and pressing cursor while loading Ubuntu I can get a TTY session. From there I tried to purge fglrx, install fglrx and many other things, but no effect so far.

Comment: ok, eventually I shrinked the Ubuntu partition, created a new one and I installed another Ubuntu (finally, I have working Ubuntu!). By that I can reach all my files (like firefox profile for example). Maybe some day I will repair the old system, but it was really strange...

Answer (score 0):

That post on Ubuntu Forums is over 4 years old - newer drivers have been released since then.

For Radeon drivers, this is my method.

1. Boot up and when the black screen appears, press some of the cursor keys and a box appears with an X server error.
2. Press CTRL + ALT + F1 to get a tty terminal.
3. Log in as root. The password is your own password that you set during installation.
4. Remove the Xorg drivers. `apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon`
5. Reboot
6. Repeat steps 1-3
7. `apt-get update`
8. `apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle-updates`
9. `aticonfig --initial`

10.Reboot.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I tried it, but it doesn't help